# express4.2.0 session is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, undefined

I am finding a trouble to set a session with node.js using express4.2.0 I show you my code and after I comment:

---

## APP.js

```
var express         = require('express');
var path            = require('path');
var favicon         = require('static-favicon');
var logger          = require('morgan');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var cookieSession   = require('cookie-session');

var mainModel       = require('./model/main_model');

var users           = require('./routes/users');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieSession({
    keys: ['secret1', 'secret2']
}));
app.use('/users', users);
/*Evething that express makes automatically*/
app.listen(8080);
```

---

## USERS.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var router      = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) 
{
    if(req.cookie && req.cookie.user) res.send("COOKIE");
    else if(req.session && req.session.user) res.send("SESSION");
    else    res.render('users/new_user', {title:"NEW USER"});
});
/*there is more content... but not relevant. */

function makeTheUserSession(result, res)
{
    result['go'] = '/users';
    //res.session.user = result.result[0];
    //res.cookie('user', result.result[0]);
    res.send(result);
}
```

---

The function makeTheUserSession is call from the method post of '/users' (to find a users on the data base).

If I uncomment the res.session.user line, when I invoque makeTheUserSession the app breaks, stop, capito, dead (Cannot set property 'user' of undefined)... 
If I uncomment the res.cookie('user', result... line, when I invke the function, and after I see the browser cookies on the settings I found a cookie called user with the values of result.result[0]... but after on the get method it doesn´t works how I expect... res never sends me "COOKIE".

I had sawn the same question many times repeated, but I didn´t see a answer that worth for me: some ones talk about connect middleware (I am using express), other say to use "app.use(express.session(keyword)) but it only works with the old version of express. The express-session module is deprecated, and I would want to use a more actuallity middleware.

I hope your answers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `req.session` not `res.session`, fix that and you should be good to go.